# What is this syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT - Jruby 9.0.0.0 pr1, Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby, rake, jruby, rake-task

I am sure this is something really dumb, but I cannot see it:

```
desc "Create an Api Key assuming one doesn't exist."
task :create_api_key, [:name] => :enviroment do  | t, args |
  if !ApiKey.find_by_application_name(args[:name])
    if ApiKey.new(name: args[:name], api_key: SecureRandom.hex(32)).save!
      puts "Your key is: " + ApiKey.find_by_application_name(args[:name]).api_key
    else
      puts "Could not create the api key, you might be missing an argument: Application Name."
    end
  else
    puts "This application already contains an api key."
  end
end
```

Line 5: `puts "Your key is: " + ApiKey.find_by_application_name(args[:name]).api_key`

throws:

```
rake aborted!
SyntaxError: /Users/Adam/Documents/Rails-Projects/BlackBird/lib/tasks/create_api_key.rake:5: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT
```

Last I checked `puts` and `+` were acceptable in ruby. Unless I am really dumb. What am I missing?

I should mention I am using **Jruby 900 Preview 1** and **Rails 4.2**

Comment: Cannot reproduce. No syntax errors in that code in Ruby 2.1.0, and there are no constants anywhere.

Comment: @meager Updated, should I report a bug to the jruby people then? oO because this is odd.

Comment: @meagar you should definitely report this ... but first try to isolate it into minimal code `puts 'Blah' + 1.to_s` or something similar that reproduces

Comment: Could this be an whitespace issue? Are you on a mac? shift + alt + space is evil.

Comment: @meagar: I also couldn't reproduce it on a slightly older dev build of both JRuby-9.0.0.0 and JRuby-9.0.0.0+graal. However, there *are* four uses of constants in that code, `SecureRandom` once and `ApiKey` thrice, including on the line in question.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Right again. Sorry, I was under the impression that constants were in `CONSTANT_CASE`, but a leading upper-case letter denotes a constant.

Comment: Accept `SecureRandom` is a valid ruby class and `ApiKey` is a known and defined model class. I have tests for it that pass. So if they are considered constants they are valid ones at that.

Comment: Those who mentioned white space, my editor removes white space upon save, my tabs are two spaces.
Also I did report this just in case it is a bug.

Comment: @TheWebs: It's irrelevant whether your constants are defined or valid builtin Ruby classes. you have a `SyntaxError`. The code doesn't even get parsed. Whether or not the constant hypothetically would have been defined if the code were hypothetically running is completely irrelevant, since the code never runs in the first place. There's either a `SyntaxError` in your code or a bug in the parser, the constant could be undefined and named `Frobnifrotz`, it wouldn't matter.

Comment: Its determined that it is a parser error, not by the bug people. But by at least 10 other people who are much more experienced at ruby, the issue is with the line in question. As this task works with regular ruby (2.2.0 to be exact)